# find serial number of USB drive using drive letter c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, wmi

```
ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
    ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
    MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
```

this piece of code returns the serial number of USB drive, but i need to find serial number using drive letter or path of drive (for a specific drive)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see to get the serial number is using Win32 (PInvoke):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var volumeInfo = VolumeInformation.GetVolumeInformation("c");
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{ Volume,nq} ({ Name,nq })")]
class VolumeInformation
{
    #region Fields

    private const int BufferLength = 256;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Volume
    {
        get;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
    }

    public uint SerialNumber
    {
        get;
    }

    public string SystemName
    {
        get;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    private VolumeInformation(string volume, string name, uint serialNumber, string systemName)
    {
        Volume = volume;
        Name = name;
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        SystemName = systemName;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool GetVolumeInformation(string letter, StringBuilder name, uint nameSize, out uint serialNumber, out uint serialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder systemName, uint systemNameSize);

    public static VolumeInformation GetVolumeInformation(string volume)
    {
        var name = new StringBuilder(BufferLength);
        var systemName = new StringBuilder(BufferLength);
        var serialNumber = 0u;
        var serialNumberLength = 0u;
        var flags = 0u;

        volume = (volume ?? String.Empty).Trim();

        if(volume.Length == 1)
        {
            volume = $"{volume}:\\";
        }
        if(!volume.EndsWith(@"\"))
        {
            volume = $"{volume}\\";
        }

        if (GetVolumeInformation(volume, name, BufferLength, out serialNumber, out serialNumberLength, out flags, systemName, BufferLength))
        {
            return new VolumeInformation(volume, name.ToString(), serialNumber, systemName.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I haven't populated the flag info, but that is discernible from the flags being returned from Win32.